# Does earths gravitational force decreases?

Tags: gravity, earth

I feel that attractive gravitational forces on Earth is somewhat similar to attractive magnetic forces. However, because the magnet loses some of its attractive force over time, will gravitational forces also decrease?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gravitational force exerted by an object depends on an objects energy content. (i.e. the Earth's mass in this case.) The gravitational force won't decay or decrease in the way you mention, because the Earth's mass more or less remains constant.(If we ignore ridiculously improbable events like a huge chunk of the Earth disappearing, that is. Large earthquakes don't change the Earth's mass either, they only alter its distribution a bit.)

Also, it'd be a wrong view to consider purely magnetic forces and gravitational ones as similar, both mostly have different properties!

Comment: Actually, ignoring other possible effects like meteorites and supernovas, I think with enough time, the atoms in the entire earth would decay and reduce the energy content, thereby reducing the gravitational force. But that would be on the cosmic scale like a few trillion years and it would only decrease a little.

Comment: Yeah, I accept that, but OP describing the gravitational force case as similar to the magnet one implies that they are thinking about a much smaller timescale, and hence I thought I shouldn't include this. (Mainly because of the very little mass decrease and immense timescale.)